# examples of random variables that the result of their preimage is not in F?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

let's assume we have a probability space $(\Omega , F , P)$.

and we have a random variable $X$ defined as : $X : \Omega \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$

and we also use a Borel set ($\mathcal{B}$).(making the alternative probability space $(\Omega , \Bbb{R} , \mathcal{B})$ )

now due to the "Measure-theoretic definition" of a random variable (as Wikipedia says)

> for every subset $A\in \mathcal{B}$, its preimage $X^{-1}(A)\in \mathcal{F}$

so this means even after defining a random variable $X$ we are not done . we should also check weather the condition above is satisfied .

what i want are some non trivial examples of random variables that do not satisfy the condition above . and what challenges may arise when trying to satisfy the above condition ?

i can think of a trivial one like this:

if we assume we are flipping a coin and

$\Omega = \{ H ,T \}$

$F = \{ \Omega , \emptyset \} $

and we define : $X(H) = 1$ , $X(T) = 0$

then $X^{-1}(-\infty,0] = \{ T \}$ which is not in $F$ .

and by the way in the case above (assuming we can only cahnge the definition of the random variable) can we say that there does not exist a random variable for that probability space ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you first define a function $X$, then, if you can demonstrate that its preimage is in the $\sigma$-algebra $F$, it is a random variable.

As an example let's say you have a deck of 52 card well shuffled, so $\Omega=\{\text{cards in the deck}\}$. Let's say that you want to know the probability of extracting an even card (i.e. a card with an even number). You can define $A=\{\text{extract an even card}\}$. Then your $\sigma$-algebra generated by $A$ is $$\sigma(A)=\{\Omega,A,A^c,\emptyset\}$$

Our probability space then is $(\Omega,\sigma(A),\mathbb P)$. The function $X:\Omega\to\{0,1\}$ such that $X(\omega)=1$ if the card $\omega$ is a face and $X=0$ otherwise is not a random variable for that probability space, because its preimage is not in the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(A)$

Comment: in the case of your example can we solve the problem by assuming the sigma field is $2^{\Omega}$?

Comment: Yes, we could, if you can choose the $\sigma$-field on your own.